# RMDir /r leaves the directory empty - but don't removes it

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation

I have an NSIS script with a `RMDir /r` instruction that is not removing the target directory (it's just emptying it).

```
$ makensis -version
v16-Dec-2013.cvs
$ pwd
/Users/mgarciaisaia/.wine/drive_c
$ ls
Program Files   users       windows
$ wine ~/InstallerTest.exe 
$ ls
InstallerTest   Program Files   users       windows
$ find InstallerTest
InstallerTest
InstallerTest/SomeData
InstallerTest/SomeData/some-file.txt
InstallerTest/SomeData/Uninstall.exe
$ wine InstallerTest/SomeData/Uninstall.exe 
$ ls
InstallerTest   Program Files   users       windows
$ find InstallerTest
InstallerTest
```

The problem is **not** about using wine in MacOSX (the same happens on Windows).

I've trimmed my `installer.nsi` to this example:

```
  !addplugindir nsis
  !define MUI_PRODUCT "InstallerTest"
  CRCCheck On
  !include "MUI2.nsh"
  Name "${MUI_PRODUCT}"
  BrandingText "${MUI_PRODUCT}"

  OutFile "InstallerTest.exe"

  ShowInstDetails "nevershow"
  ShowUninstDetails "nevershow"

  !define SOME_DATA "C:\InstallerTest\SomeData"

  !define MUI_ABORTWARNING
  Caption "${MUI_PRODUCT} Installer"
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Section "Install" Install
  DetailPrint "Installing..."

  SetOutPath "${SOME_DATA}"
  File "some-file.txt"
  WriteUninstaller "${SOME_DATA}\Uninstall.exe"
SectionEnd

Section "un.Remove InstallTest"
  DetailPrint "Removing..."

;Delete Files
  RMDir /r "${SOME_DATA}"
  Delete "${SOME_DATA}\Uninstall.exe"
SectionEnd
```

**What's that I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: Why are you using some random version? The current alpha should be better than anything from 2013.

Comment: @Anders: I'm using the current `makensis` version available in Homebrew - it's not _that_ random.

Comment: Between v2.46 and v3.0a2 there were many points in time where the code in trunk was broken or buggy and I would not recommend using snapshots from that era. v16-Dec-2013.cvs probably falls into that category.

Answer (score 0):

Put `Delete "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"` before `RMDir`, not after.

Edit:

If some other program has a open handle to the folder or something inside the folder then RMDir will not be able to delete it.

On Windows I would tell you to use Sysinternals Process Monitor to see why the delete fails, I don't know if that will work under WINE or if your "host OS" is preventing the delete in some way...

Comment: That made no difference :/ (even putting `Delete "${SOME_DATA}\Uninstall.exe"`, as it should)

Comment: Both RMDir and Delete should use $instdir in a real situation, not a define with a path to something on your local machine.

Comment: The point is in my real case I'm trying to remove some data directories of the app that _need_ to be outside the `$INSTDIR`. That's a requirement, and I don't have a choice in that.